# One to One mapping on the same entity remove issue Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-one

I have an entity Product that can be linked to another product of the same type ( So one to one mapping from Product to Product ).

The problem occurs when I'm trying to remove the product from the database because it has a foreign key.

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM product WHERE id = ?' with params ["25"]:
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`acme`.`product`, CONSTRAINT `FK_BAD80AF68031A592` FOREIGN KEY (`linked_to_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`))

This is how I defined the relationship

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="linked_to_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $linkedTo;
```

Any ideas what to set on the relationship to avoid this FK removal issue?

Comment: Did you check that `doctrine:migration:diff` is empty? 
If so maybe onDelete="CASCADE" instead of cascade={"remove"}  will solve this issue. Of course if you need to process events such as preRemove/postRemove on child items , this will not be a good solution

Comment: @AlexVeryutin that worked, thanks